# Does the blocksize (bs) value in swap settings matter? If yes, is there a command to show current settings about swap block size?

Tags: swap

This post gives this command to resize swap

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=8
```

Does the blocksize (bs) value in swap settings matter? If yes, is there a command to show current settings about swap block size?

If swap block size really affect something, I would like to know what it would be before I modify the settings.

If not, please explain a little bit why swap block size would not actually affect the performance of swap.

Some additional reference would be better.

Comment: I don't think the blocksize (`bs`) value that you pass to `dd` has any effect on the properties of the swapfile that's generated - it just tells `dd` what sized blocks of zero bytes to read and write when initializing the file. (A file doesn't really have a blocksize - that's a property of the file*system* on which it resides.)

Comment: @steeldriver  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I'll wait a bit in case anyone who understands it better provides an answer...

Comment: What makes the file a swap area is the `mkswap`-command which is issued after the `dd`-command.

Answer (score 2):

According to the following link, this is the way to read the NUL bytes in /dev/zero (using blocks), only the `bs` x `count` value matters.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/ the block size is the number of bytes to read and write at a time.
Most places recommend 1k (1024).
The [following article](http://blog.tdg5.com/tuning-dd-block-size/) shows a way to determine the best block size.